# Get Deployment annotation from a Kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes

Each Kubernetes deployment gets this annotation:

```
$ kubectl describe deployment/myapp
Name:                   myapp
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Sat, 24 Mar 2018 23:27:42 +0100
Labels:                 app=myapp
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision=5
```

Is there a way to read that annotation (`deployment.kubernetes.io/revision`) from a pod that belongs to the deployment?

I tried Downward API, but that only allows to get annotations of the pod itself (not of its deployment).

Answer (score 12):

```
kubectl get pod POD_NAME -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with the code.

Comment: @M-- what this command does is it extracts the annotations from the metadata section of the resource definition. jsonpath type output can be used to navigate the resource definition.

Comment: @NandunThilinaBandara I am asking for an explanation to increase the quality of the answer, not that I had a question about it. In any case, thanks.

Comment: @M - Hello, i've not worked with k8s for last 2 years. So i would leave the answer as is, because it seems it helps some people. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

It has been a long time but here is what I do to get a specific annotation :

```
kubectl get ing test -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class}'
```

So for you it would be :

```
kubectl get deploy myapp -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.deployment\.kubernetes\.io/revision}'
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can leverage both using a kubectl selector to query all pods with label `app=myapp` and **jq** to query and format the resulting json to get you the name and annotations for each of the pods

```
kubectl get po -l app=myapp -o=json | jq '[. | {pod: .items[].metadata}][] | {name: .pod.name, annotations: .pod.annotations}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the annotation from a pod using below command:

```
kubectl describe pod your_podname
```

and you will find Annotations section with all annotation for pod.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible by the below command-

`kubectl get pod myapp -n=default -o yaml | grep -A 8 annotations:`

`kubectl get pod myapp -n=default -o yaml` gets all the details of the pod myapp in default namespace in yaml format.

`grep -A 8 metadata:` searches for keyword 'annotations' and displays 8 lines as specified by A 8 to show all the annotations

Answer (score 0):

Command to list annotations for all pods

> kubectl annotate pod  --list --all

Command to get annotation for only one specific pod

> kubectl annotate pod my-pod --list

Command to get  annotation for one or more specific pod

> kubectl annotate pod my-pod1 my-pod2 --list

Answer (score -1):

to get only the annotations section of the pod you can use

```
kubectl get pod YOUR_POD_NAME | get -i 'annotations'
```

you can also use jsonPath like

```
kubectl get pod YOUR_POD_NAME -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}{"\n"}'
```

Comment: you cant specify output in describe command, only in get